# How to generate 4 random numbers between 1-10 and have one declared a winner (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, random, numbers, generator

I'm trying to create a random number generator.  so far I have

```
<script>
   var arr = []
  while (arr.length < 4) {
    var randomnum = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)
    var found = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i] == randomnum) {
        found = true;
        break
      }
    }
    if (!found) arr[arr.length] = randomnum;
  }
  document.write(arr);     
</script>
```

But instead of having the numbers display in line, i'd like to have it say "person a rolls __, Person b rolls __, etc" but I have no idea how to do that through javascript.

Also, how would I declare a winner, like "Person A Wins" (the winner being the highest roller)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The questions in the title and the body seem to differ. Simply iterate over the array and output what you want to output for each number. To get the highest number in the array, have a look at any of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+maximum+value++array

Answer (score 0):

Sticking as much to your code, I would:

1. Compute the maximum within the loop.
2. Find the index of the person based on that maximum, with [Array.indexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp)

**HTML**

```
<p>Person A rolls <span id="pa"></span></p>
<p>Person B rolls <span id="pb"></span></p>
<p>Person C rolls <span id="pc"></span></p>
<p>Person D rolls <span id="pd"></span></p>
<p>Person <span id="winner"></span> wins!</p>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var x = document.getElementById("x");
var arr = [];
var max = 0; // <-- new code
  while (arr.length < 4) {
    var randomnum = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)
    var found = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i] == randomnum) {
        found = true;
        break
      }
    }
    if (!found) arr[arr.length] = randomnum;
    if (randomnum > max) max = randomnum;  // <-- new code
  }

// new code
 document.getElementById("pa").innerHTML = arr[0];
 document.getElementById("pb").innerHTML = arr[1];
document.getElementById("pc").innerHTML = arr[2];
 document.getElementById("pd").innerHTML = arr[3];
 var players = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
 document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = players[arr.indexOf(max)];
```

** DEMO**

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rjuecrr6/).

Answer (score 0):

A proposal with

- [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

  > The `every()` method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function.
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

  > The `map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.
- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

  > The `reduce()` method applies a function against an accumulator and each value of the array (from left-to-right) to reduce it to a single value.

```js
var arr = [],
    persons = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    maxIndex;

// set all random numbers
while (arr.length < 4) {
    var randomnum = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)
    arr.every(function (a) {
        return a !== randomnum;
    }) && arr.push(randomnum);
}

// write results for every person
document.write(arr.map(function (a, i) {
    return 'Person ' + persons[i] + ' rolls ' + a + '.';
}).join('<br>'));

// get the max index
maxIndex = arr.reduce(function (r, a, i, aa) {
    return a > aa[r] ? i : r;
}, 0);

document.write('<p>Winner is person ' + persons[maxIndex] + ' with ' + arr[maxIndex] + '.</p>');
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var list_numbers = []
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
  var randomnum=Math.ceil(Math.random()*10)
  $("#numbers").append("<li>Your number is "+randomnum+"</li>")
  list_numbers.push(randomnum)
}
//this is the most important bit, using apply to get the biggest number in an array
$("#numbers").append("<p>Highest number is "+Math.max.apply(Math, list_numbers)+"</p>")
```

```html
<!--jquery just to output in html -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="numbers"></ul>
<div id="highest_number"></div>
```

Comment: Code without an explanation is not very helpful.

Comment: OP doesn't have jQuery tag on question either

Comment: @charlietfl I don't use jquery in my code. it is just to output to html which OP doesn't need (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273049/stack-snippets-console-output)

Comment: well it's pretty obvious that OP is very much a beginner...so mixing libraries in doesn't make sense and there is no mention of a library being used. OP may not recognize it. jQuery is right in middle of the loop ... OP is now dependent on it if they try to run this themselves

Comment: Yeah, I'm a total beginner.  That's pretty much what I need though, so thanks!.  Is it possible to differentiate each number like, Person A,B,C and D? and instead of just declaring the highest number, declaring which person got the highest?